# How to remove the last part of a file path

Tags: c

I need to remove the last part of a file path.

For example, if I have this filename `"user/doc/file1"`, I want to be able to get `"user/doc/"`.

Comment: "PS my qsn is different than the recommended solution" - if you ask for `realpath(".")` and take the last two elements of the returned path, I think you have a solution. _If_ I understand what you are asking correctly, that is!

Comment: If your question is different, please explain how, and also clarify what you are trying to do : )

Comment: Please elaborate your question, it's really unclear what you're asking. As your question stands here I'd just answer: "remove the `..` from `user/doc/..` to get `user/doc/`"

Comment: @MichaelWalz yea you understood my question. Any C library to do that parsing ? using strtok  with separator ".." work?

Comment: @Samun so your question is totally misleading. Are you asking this: "I have a string that ends with `".."`. How can I remove the `".."` from the end of the string? Example: original string `"user/doc/.."`, string I want: `"user/doc/"`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  sorry that my qsn being unclear. So if i have a string "user/doc/file1", I want to remove "file1" and expect the final result be 
user/doc/.

Comment: @Samun please [edit]  your question and make clear what _exactly_ you want. Your last comment isn't very clear either. Don't be sorry if your question is not clear, but make it clear instead.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I just edited. hope that helps.

Comment: @Samun please don't put clarfifications in comment but **[edit]** your question and make all clarifications _there_. Or just ask a new question and delete this one.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  i updated qsn too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char string[] = "/user/doc/file1";

  // find pointer to last '/' in string
  char *lastslash = strrchr(string, '/');

  if (lastslash)           // if found
    *(lastslash + 1) = 0;  //   terminate the string right after the '/'

  printf ("string = %s\n", string);
}
```

Output

```
string = /user/doc/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this is exactly what i wished to do

Comment: You need to decide what the result should be if the user inputs "/user/doc/". Should it be "/user/" or "/user/doc/" ?